# Programming style in OCaml

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, ocaml

I have a question about the correct way to write efficient functional programs. Suppose I'm given a list s of positive ints, and I want to find the minimum element (or just 0 if empty). Then a generic functional program for doing this would look like

```
minList s =
    | [] -> undefined
    | [x] -> x
    | x :: t -> min x (minList t)
```

In a lazy language one can make this more efficient by adding an extra clause which terminates the recursion if a zero is found - this way s is only computed up to the first zero

```
minList s = 
    | [] -> undefined
    | [x] -> x
    | x :: t -> if x==0 then 0 else min x (minList t)
```

However, am I correct in believing that this sort of trick would not work in a strict evaluation language like OCaml, which would evaluate the whole of s before running minList? If so, what would be the correct way to optimize this in OCaml?

ADDITIONAL QUESTION: Ok, so if I understand that if statements are always lazy. But what about the following, for example: I have a function on int lists again which first checks whether or not the ith element is zero i.e.

```
f s = if s(i)==0 then 0 else g s
```

Here the input sequence s is present in both clauses of the if statement, but clearly for an efficient computation you would only want to evaluate s(i) in the first case. Here, would OCaml always evaluate all of s, even if the first case succeeds?

Comment: it would absolutely work. You would never evaluate the false side of the if statement if the boolean expression is true --that would cause a lot of problems in ANY language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if` expressions in ocaml don't follow the strict evaluation rule.
Like || and &&, it's lazily evaluated.
See this link: [if expressions](http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~dmatusze/resources/ocaml/ocaml.html#If%20expressions)

Answer (score 1):

In a strictly evaluated language, the whole list `s` would be evaluated. Still,

```
minList s = 
    | [] -> 0
    | x :: t -> if x==0 then 0 else min x (minList t)
```

would not scan the whole list if a `0` is found.

The `if` construct has a "non-strict" semantics, in that it will evaluate only one branch, and not both. This holds in both strict and non strict languages.

An actual difference would be when calling a "user defined if" such as (using Haskell syntax):

```
myIf :: Bool -> a -> a
myIf b x y = if b then x else y
```

In a non strict language, calling `myIf True 3 (nonTerminatingFunction ())` would yield `3`, while in a strict language the same expression would loop forever.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the minimum of an empty list is undefined, not `0`. This makes sense, otherwise `minList [1,2,3]` would be `0` which is clearly not true. This is what `ghci` has to say:

```hs
Prelude> minimum []
*** Exception: Prelude.minimum: empty list
```

Hence your function should be written as:

```ml
let minList (x::t) = min x (minList t)
```

---

There are some problems with this definition though:

1. It will still give an error because there's no pattern match for the empty list.
2. It is not tail recursive.
3. It doesn't stop if the head is `0`.

So here's a better solution:

```
let minimum x xs = match x,xs
  | 0,xs        -> 0
  | x,[]        -> x
  | x,(y :: ys) -> minimum (min x y) ys

let minList = function
  | [] -> raise Failure "No minimum of empty list"
  | x::t -> minimum x t
```

The advantage of writing it like this is that `minimum` is tail recursive. Hence it will not increase the stack size. In addition if the head is `0` it will immediately return `0`.

Lazy evaluation has no play here.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. Yeah, silly mistake in my original code. My main query, though, was whether or not lazy evaluation had any role in 'if' or pattern matching statements, and I think this has been clarified now in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

In almost every modern programming language:

for `expr1 && expr2`, if expr1 is already false, then expr2 won't be evaluated.

for `expr1 || expr2`, if expr1 is already true, then expr2 won't be evaluated.

OCaml does this too.